# A 4-year old question suddenly became "active" today, why?

Tags: support, questions, bump

In the "interesting" tab I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114394/creating-a-self-extracting-executable-in-c-sharp). It was asked 4 years ago, but the latest activity was "today":

[image]

However, there were neither new comments nor answers. Why has it become active?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13674986

Comment: Now I've noticed that user Grault edited one of the answers today. Was that the reason?

Comment: [The top answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8114458/3853934) has been edited 15 minutes ago.

Comment: BTW, if you're in the question list, and you click into a question and it looks as if nothing changed, you can go back to the list and click on the "modified 5 minutes ago" (or whatever) and it should take you to the question or answer that was modified. Sometimes that doesn't work (esp. if it was modified by Community), but mostly it does. Mostly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of its [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8114458/4751173) was edited a few minutes ago:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that right after posting the question :(